# Unfortunately my app has Stopped error

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

i Created a Slide menu Using Sherlock Library
when  i want To Start Fragment With Sliding Menu After login Sliding Menu Is not Starting giving Unfortunatly error ..When I Debug my debugger stopped at

```
    rlProfile.setOnClickListener(this);   at this line
```

here Is My Log Cat error

```
09-09 12:04:23.662: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 12:04:23.662: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.phonebook/com.example.phonebook.SlidingMenuDrawer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 12:04:23.662: E/AndroidRuntime(6560): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 12:04:23.662: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at com.example.phonebook.SlidingMenuDrawer.initMenu(SlidingMenuDrawer.java:140)
09-09 12:04:23.662: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at com.example.phonebook.SlidingMenuDrawer.onCreate(SlidingMenuDrawer.java:83)
09-09 12:04:23.662: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-09 12:04:23.662: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-09 12:04:23.662: E/AndroidRuntime(6560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2031)
```

here Is my Code

SlidingDrawer

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    initMenu();

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerList = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, // host Activity
            mDrawerLayout, // DrawerLayout object
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav drawer image to replace 'Up' image
            R.string.drawer_open, // "open drawer" description for accessibility
            R.string.drawer_close // "close drawer" description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        switchFragment(new Category());
        setSelected(rlHome);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList); // Keep drawer open by default
    }

}

private void initMenu() {
    UserModel user=(UserModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("User");

    rlProfile = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlProfile);
    rlHome = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlHome);
    rlUploads = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlUploads);
    rlSubscriptions = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlSubscriptions);
    rlFav = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlFav);
    rlPlaylists = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlPlaylists);
    rlHistory = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlHistory);

    ivMenuFacebook = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivMenuFacebook);
    ivMenuTwitter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivMenuTwitter);
    ivMenuShare = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivMenuShare);

    rlProfile.setOnClickListener(this);
    rlHome.setOnClickListener(this);
    rlUploads.setOnClickListener(this);
    rlSubscriptions.setOnClickListener(this);
    rlFav.setOnClickListener(this);
    rlPlaylists.setOnClickListener(this);
    rlHistory.setOnClickListener(this);

    ivMenuFacebook.setOnClickListener(this);
    ivMenuTwitter.setOnClickListener(this);
    ivMenuShare.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageloader= new ImageLoaderThumbnail(getApplicationContext());
    String Img_url=user.getUser_Image();

          ImageView i=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.avatar);
          imageloader.DisplayImage(Img_url, i);
    /*      Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
        .load(Img_url).transform(new RoundedImageView()).into(i);*/
          String Username=user.getUser_Full_Name();
          TextView username=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
          username.setText(Username);


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }
    return true;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment newContent = new Category();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    if (v.getId() == R.id.rlProfile) {
        // PROFILE
        newContent = new Welcome();
        bundle.putString(CUR_PAGE_TITLE, "Profile");
        setTitle("Profile");
        setSelected(rlProfile);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.rlHome) {
        // HOME
        setTitle("Home");
        bundle.putString(CUR_PAGE_TITLE, "Home");
        setSelected(rlHome);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.rlUploads) {
        // UPLOADS
        setTitle("Uploads");
        bundle.putString(CUR_PAGE_TITLE, "Uploads");
        setSelected(rlUploads);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.rlSubscriptions) {
        // Subscriptions
        newContent = new MeetPeople();
        setTitle("Meet People");
        bundle.putString(CUR_PAGE_TITLE, "Meet People");
        setSelected(rlSubscriptions);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.rlPlaylists) {
        // PLAYLISTS
        newContent = new FriendsActivity();
        setTitle("Friends");
        bundle.putString(CUR_PAGE_TITLE, "Friends");
        setSelected(rlPlaylists);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.rlHistory) {
        // HISTORY
        newContent = new SettingProfile();
        setTitle("History");
        bundle.putString(CUR_PAGE_TITLE, "History");
        setSelected(rlHistory);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.rlFav) {
        // FAVOURITES
        setTitle("Favourites");
        bundle.putString(CUR_PAGE_TITLE, "Favourites");
        setSelected(rlFav);
    }

    // SHARE
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.ivMenuFacebook) {
        // FACEBOOK
        Toast.makeText(this, "Facebook pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.ivMenuTwitter) {
        // TWITTER
        Toast.makeText(this, "Twitter pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.ivMenuShare) {
        // SHARE
        Toast.makeText(this, "Share pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (newContent != null) {
        newContent.setArguments(bundle);
        switchFragment(newContent);
    }

}
```

Comment: is rlProfile component of activity_main this xml?

Comment: rlProfile is null so check your xml layout .

Comment: Post your xml layout...will help everyone to solve it!!

Comment: Thnxxx All I Solved my Problem